# Working with the index of mapped elements?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, parameters

I have a React app that shows 12 elements in the page. Each element is comming from an array and I use the map method to render them in the page. 
To build this I created a class called Tags:

```
export default class Tags {
public title: string;
public id: string;
public active: boolean;

constructor(title: string, id: string, active: boolean) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.active = active;
}
```

}

And a container tsx file that render these 12 elements: 
This line call a method called renderTags that render the elements on the page. It fetch the elements from an array called allTags and apply the map method on it:

```
<div  className={styles.tagCloud}>
              {this.state.allTags.slice(0, 12).map((t,index) => this.renderTags(t,index))}

        </div>
```

This is the renderTags method. Here there is a call to another method called collectTags nad I pass the clicked element and the index:

```
private renderTags(tag: Tags, index:number) {

    return <div>
        <p onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); this.collectTags(tag,index); return false;}}>
            # {tag.title} <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--CirclePlus"></i>
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

and this is the collectTags. Here I am trying to access to the "active" property of the clicked element using the index that was sent from the renderTags method:

```
private collectTags(tags: Tags, index: any): any {
   console.log('TAG INDEX: ' + Tags[index]);
   Tags[index].active = true;

}
```

Here when i click on an element the console.log says that Tags[index] is undefuned. I was expecting to get the index of the clicked element. Whe I run console.log to Tags I get an object returned (the clicked element) and if I test the index parameter in the console I get the index for the clicked element. But together, Tags[index], I get undefined.

How can I update the active parameter of the clicked element, I was thinking something like this:

```
Tags[index].active = true;
```

Regards
Americo

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tags[index]` ? `Tags` is your type

Comment: I tried with tags[index] and I get undefined aswell :-(

Comment: But anyway, if you map over an array of all tags you pass down a single element (tag) to the next function. Therefore the `tags` variable in `collectTags` is actually a single tag.